# ¿Como concatenar .then en una promesa en Vue?

Tags: javascript, promesas

intento concatenar promesas para un cronometro que alterna turnos de actividad con descanso. Soy nuevo con las promesas y no sé porque no me funciona el .then
Tengo una funcion/metodo "timer" como esta:

```
    timer: function(seconds) {
        var myself = this;
        myself.digits=seconds;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            crono = setInterval(
                function() {
                    myself.digits--;
                    if (myself.digits <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(this.crono);
                        resolve("done");
                    }
                }, 1000);
        });
    },
```

Que es llamada por otro metodo como este:

```
    go: function() {
        this.a.running = 1;
        var myself=this;
        this.timer(10)
        .then(function(){myself.timer(myself.a.act_time)})
        .then(function(){myself.timer(myself.a.act_desc)});
    },
```

El primer "paso" lo hace correctamente, cuenta diez segundos y pasa al primer `then`, pero el segundo `then` lo ejecuta al mismo tiempo que el primero. ¿como deberia ponerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada la pregunta es independiente de Vue.

Segundo, tu pregunta de cómo concatenar promesas, es muy sencilla.

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('Success!');
  // or
  // reject ("Error!");
});
p1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // Success!
}, function(reason) {
  console.log(reason); // Error!
}).then(function(value) {
  console.log("2",value); // Success!
}, function(reason) {
  console.log("2",reason); // Error!
});
```

Entonces el **then** es ejecutado una vez que la promesa es resuelta, y regresa una promesa. De esta manera se pueden concatener. Pero en el ejemplo si te das cuenta, el primer then no regresa nada, por lo que se resuelve con `undefined`.

Tercero, lo que se puede inferir que quieres lograr es un intervalo cada `x` tiempo y al terminar otro de `y`tiempo
Digamos 25 minutos, y luego 5 minutos y así.

Para lograrlo si puedes hacer uso de `setInterval` y `setTimeout`. Pero cuando formules la pregunta adecuada, con mucho gusto te la respondemos : )

Comment: Ok, no me has resuelto la duda al 100% pero me has puesto en el camino correcto para resolverla. 
Ya lo tenia funcionando con `setInterval` pero queria hacerlo con promesas por limpieza y aprender a usarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he conseguido envolviendo las llamadas al timer() en promesas, no sé si sera la mejor forma:

```
            .then(function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    resolve(myself.timer(myself.a.act_time))
                })
            })
            .then(function() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    resolve(myself.timer(20))
                })
            })
```